# Feathers.js - Content Type - GET

Tags: express, feathersjs

Im trying to get a picture from my feathers server over the GET method. Trying to call the server over

> http://localhost:3030/uploads/945fdcbc5ef41f8d301c14d8cfb3c4ae536f4bffc0338091043ec5cf27b9bcff.png

should return an image. Instead i get a response like:

> {"id":"945fdcbc5ef41f8d301c14d8cfb3c4ae536f4bffc0338091043ec5cf27b9bcff.png","uri":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACoCAMAAABt9SM9AAABqlBMVEV/f38AAAD///....... " }

My question is: Is it right that i get a Json response and have to change the "responded" content-type to data:image/png to see the picture directly in the Browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show this image directly on a website by using `<img src="${data.uri}">`.

It is also possible to change the content type and response in a [custom service middleware](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#custom-service-middleware) converting the data URI to a buffer:

```
app.use('/uploads', uploadService, (req, res) => {
  // res.data is the response. We need only the base64 payload without the prefix
  const base64Data = res.data.uri.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
  const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64');

  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  res.send(buffer);
});
```

This should now show an image when visiting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Daff! My code works now with this solution:

```
app.use(
    "/uploads",uploadservice.....,
     (req, res, next) => {
      const base64Data = res.data.uri.replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
      const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, "base64");
      res.set("Content-Type", "image/png");
      res.send(buffer);
      next();
    }
  );
```